# There is any way to get ClientIDMode and ClientID property on ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to have the brand new `ClientIDMode` and the `ClientID` property on ASP.NET 3.5 controls, there is any way I can achieve that?

I was thinking in replacing the default control compiler, this is possible or there is many changes to make this behavior available?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want `ClientIDMode.Static` over your control id's, you can use the following workaround:

```
HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
p.Attributes.Add("id", "myParagraph");
this.Controls.Add(p);
```

prints:

```
<p id="myParagraph"></p>
```

Comment: Static is what I want, but will this work on other controls besides HtmlGenericControl? Does it override the default ID behavior?

Comment: What if it is a Repeater Control?

Comment: A repeater control doesn't have an ID in the client?!

Comment: I think what BrunoLM is saying, is that if you have say a <p> tag in your item template for a repeater, they will all get assigned a client id of "myParagraph", which is invalid.

The point of predictable client id's is to make it easier to "predict client id's of ASP.NET server controls".

A paragraph tag is not a server control, you can set the id on the client side (HTML).

Comment: The questioner asks for `Static`. *not* for `Predicatble`. Soit.

Comment: The title is saying GET, but by his post I understood he was asking a way to set the ClientID. You can't set the ClientID of a Repeater using Attributes because it doesn't have this property...